# Size of access database increasing

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am making an application in `VB.net (4.5)` using an `Access DB (2016)`, but have a small problem.When I insert a record (eg a RichTextBox become Byte ()) the size of the database increases. But when I delete, size does not decrease (it is left untouched). Therefore, as I inserting and deleting records databases is growing in MB.

I have found that when you reboot the PC, the DB has freed space. What's the problem? How can i resolve this issue??

PD: I'm doing all .close () and .Dispose () should my DB access class.

Comment: The size limit is 2 GB (with 2010 Version - maybe changed in 2016). When you reach that limit, you can use your Access and "compact&repair". That will recover your diskspace (of course you can do the compact task on a regular basis long before reaching the limit). Although in C#, you will find this link useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866421/how-to-compact-msaccess-database-using-c-sharp

Comment: I have no problem with the limit.
I'm talking about a few test records (2-3 MB)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a feature of Access. And more generally, of almost any database system or file system.

The Database expands to hold new records. When you mark the record as deleted, the space is not reclaimed or released until later.

In the versions of Access I use, the database is (optionally) compacted when you close Access.  If you are using a com object, or a .net object, instead of MSAccess, it is up to you to use the appropriate method to compact the database.

If your file system is not showing the correct size of the file, then either (1) that is a problem with your shell not updating as expected, or (2) you aren't releasing the file correctly.

Database size after deleting is a frequently asked question. See also [Wouldn't MS Access(.mdb) file size reduce after deleting the content of database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156331/wouldnt-ms-access-mdb-file-size-reduce-after-deleting-the-content-of-database)

Comment: I see...
The "problem" I see in compaction is that a new file is usually created (with the compacted database) will end up replacing the old.

Is it possible to compaction of the same file?
The database is multiuser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you committing the database according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208950.aspx

`COMMIT [TRANSACTION | WORK]`

Can be used

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using transactions.
However, I'm not sure if that had anything to do, because when I restart my PC, the DB is OK.

```
Public Function ejecutarUpdate(ByVal query As String, ByVal devolverId As Boolean, ByRef id As Integer) As Integer
    Dim numRegistros As Integer = 0

    Try
        conexion = New OleDbConnection(cadenaConexion)
        conexion.Open()
        comando = New OleDbCommand(query, conexion)
        numRegistros = comando.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If devolverId Then
            comando.CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
            id = CInt(comando.ExecuteScalar())
        End If
    Catch oleDbException As OleDbException
        If oleDbException.Errors(0).SQLState = "3022" Then
            Throw New Exception(COD_ERROR_PK_UK) ' Restricción de PK/UK
        Else
            Throw oleDbException
        End If
    Catch exception As Exception
        Throw exception
    Finally
        liberarDB()
    End Try

    Return numRegistros
End Function

Private Sub liberarDB()
    If conexion IsNot Nothing AndAlso conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conexion.Close()
        conexion.Dispose()
        conexion = Nothing
    End If

    If comando IsNot Nothing Then
        comando.Dispose()
        comando = Nothing
    End If

    If adaptador IsNot Nothing Then
        adaptador.Dispose()
        adaptador = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```